# Do out of sync propellors make passengers more likely to be airsick?

Tags: physiology, aviation

In a multi-engine propellor-driven aircraft, propellor synchronization occurs when the two propellors are turning at the same RPM. Propellor synchronization eliminates [beating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29). The purpose is for comfort of the crew and passengers.

The claim I'd like examined is that out-of-sync propellors increases the likelihood of airsick passengers:

- "that god awful sound is enough to make passengers and pilots alike very ill after 15-20 minutes" (from the [airliners.net forum](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/125820/))
- "I don't have passengers to make sick" (from the [jetcareers.com forum](http://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/syncing-props-on-the-takeoff-roll-yes-or-no.109725/))
- "If it doesn't work it can either be slightly annoying or bad enough to make passengers sick" (from the [airliners.net forum](http://www.airliners.net/aviation-forums/tech_ops/read.main/303214))

I believe that un-synced props would be annoying or distracting, but I am doubtful that they can cause airsickness. I can imagine several mechanisms for how this could be true, but I haven't found any evidence other than anecdotes in forums.